# Two WordPress websites (each a different language) = ''?page_id=<?php the_ID(); ?>" not redirecting on the homepage properly

Tags: php, wordpress

We have two WordPress websites on two domains. One of each language.

Inside our header.php file, the following code is found:

---

The below code is shown on the French website

```
<a href="http://www.french-url.com/?page_id=<?php the_ID(); ?>">English</a>
```

The below code is shown on the English website

```
<a href="http://www.english-url.com/?page_id=<?php the_ID(); ?>">Français</a>
```

---

When we are on the English website, and click on the link to visit the French website, we get redirected to a 404 Page Not Found Error: **BECAUSE** the page is redirecting to a URL ending with a code like so '?page_id=155'.

Now, when we are on the French website, and click on the link to visit the English website, the redirection works perfectly. The URL shown is '?page_id=' **WITHOUT A NUMBER** at the end.

---

We would like to keep this code intact for every other page, except for the homepage. Say you're visiting an about-us page, or contact-us page, or a blog post, the following code should remain there:

```
?page_id=<?php the_ID()' ?>
```

Now can someone please tell me if the following scenario would make sense, and if so, please show some code on how to make it work:

**Make an if/else statement saying that if you are on the homepage, then only redirect to the chosen URL (without the added code page_ID at the end of the URL).**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the websites in question, but it sounds like all pages aside from the homepage have `?page_id=NUMBER` in the URL. if that's the case, you can do it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.english-url.com/<?php if ($_GET['page_id']){ echo '?page_id='; the_ID(); } ?>">Français</a>
```

This will only add the `?page_id=NUMBER` query into pages that have one set in their own URL.